# attach file uploading progress

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

i used javamail api to send emails with attachments from java applications, and it is just simple.

```
File f= new File(file);
MimeBodyPart mbp2 = new MimeBodyPart();

try {
    mbp2.attachFile(f);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}



Multipart mp= new MimeMultipart();
mp.addBodyPart(mbp2);

message.setContent(mp);
```

but the thing i want is to know is how to know the uploading progress of my attachment, unlike httpclient i  can't find an outputstream to writeto!
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the method implementation.

```
public void attachFile(File file) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource(file);      
    this.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
    this.setFileName(fds.getName());
}
```

You need to override FileDataSource with your custom implementation that tracks file upload.

You should override getInputStream() method to return a FilterOutputStream that count the read bytes. Apache commons-io has [CountingInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html) class that can do the job.

Then you simply have to compare the read bytes count with the file length to have a progression.

Comment: dear Toilal, is it possible to override getInputStream() to retyrn a FilterOutputStream??

Answer (score 0):

ok, i did it with overriding the DataHandler() and it works really well!

```
class progress extends DataHandler{
long len;
public idky(FileDataSource ds) {
    super(ds);
    len= ds.getFile().length();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



long transferredBytes=0;
public void writeTo(OutputStream os) throws IOException{

        InputStream instream = this.getInputStream();
        DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

      byte[] tmp = new byte[4096];
      int l;
      while ((l = instream.read(tmp)) != -1)
      {
        os.write(tmp, 0, l);
        this.transferredBytes += l;
        System.out.println(dFormat.format(((double)transferredBytes/(double)this.len)*100)+"%");

      }
      os.flush();


}
}
```

and added it to the MimeBodyPart.